# Flow not crashing when passing empty object to a type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I got this definition:

```
export type Entry = {|
  id: string,
  title: string,
|};

...

export type Props = {
  entries: Array<Entry>,
  ...

// The following is not crashing
const rowGetter = ({ index }): Entry => props.entries[index] || {};
```

Using `flow-bin@0.67.1`, the above code is not crashing. I'd have expected for it to crash, as the definition states the return value is an `Entry` type, not an empty object.

Of course if I change the definition of the arrow function as follows, it crashes as expected, saying that inexact literal doesn't match, and that properties Id and title are missing:

```
const rowGetter = ({ index }): Entry => ({});
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Flow's design regarding [potentially undefined array elements](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-array-access-is-unsafe).

Any index into `props.entries` is considered to resolve to an `Entry`, and not `undefined` in the case of the index being out of bounds (or a sparse array).

As a result the `|| {}` is not considered a viable branch and is therefore not evaluated.  In your refactoring, you've removed the array access and `{}` is correctly reported as being invalid for `Entry`.

If you change our method to:

```
const rowGetter = ({ index }): Entry => {
  if (typeof props.entries[index] !== 'undefined') {
    return props.entries[index]
  }
  return {}
}
```

Then flow will correctly report the `return {}`.